# C++ HTTP / HTML Socket Question

Tags: c++, http, sockets

I'm building an application which I'd like to have it connect to a website and parse some data off it. I'm wondering if anyone could provide me some raw example code.

I don't necessarily need help parsing, I'm just wondering in C++ how would I go about downloading the data from the page into my app so that I can start parsing the data I need out of it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check out [boost.asio](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_41_0/doc/html/boost_asio.html) [[examples](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_41_0/doc/html/boost_asio/examples.html)].

Answer (score 7):

Check out [libCurl](http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/).